# getting result value by using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using Codeigniter platform.

here is the ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/account/findpassword/exec',
            data: {
                'user_email': val
            },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result){
                if(result == 'FALSE')
                    alert('Email does not exist.');
                else if(result == 'TRUE')
                    alert('We sent a new password to your email.');                 
                else
                    alert('There is an error.');
            }
        });
```

here is controller

```
    function exec()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('user_email');

        $this->load->model('account/findpassword_model', 'findpass');
        $u_data = $this->findpass->get_user_data($email);
        if($u_data == FALSE)
        {
            $result = 'FALSE';
            echo $result;
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
        $this->findpass->set_user_newpass($u_data['u_id'], $new_pass);
        echo 'TRUE';
        }
    }
```

here is model

```
function get_user_data($email)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT u_id, u_name FROM '.T_USER_ACCOUNT.' WHERE u_email = "'.$email.'"';
        $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
        if(count($result) > 0)
            return $result[0];
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
```

It supposes to say 'email doesn't exist.' message if there is no email address.

If an email address is exist, it supposes to say the second message.

When I checked the db server, this controller and model commands worked.

However, it only says 'There is an error.' message for all types.

I checked million times, but don't know why it doesn't say right words.

Comment: Here's a hint.. it's in the top left corner of your keyboard

Comment: my actual code msg is different. I just fixed a little bit. here is the code

Comment: can you please check with firebug to see if the POST request's result is actually 'FALSE' or 'TRUE'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you only ever intend to return TRUE or FALSE back to the client. If you're not matching either of them, the question is, what is the value of result in your success handler?

`console.log(result);`

in your success function should show you what you're getting back from the server, and from there is should be easy to figure out why you're not matching TRUE or FALSE.